# Is there a way to force an update to Google Maps' offline maps on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps

On [Google Maps for iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8) (version 3.2.5.29671 as of the time of writing), I can save offline maps using the hidden trick [described here](http://gizmodo.com/how-to-save-offline-maps-in-the-new-google-maps-for-ios-819672562). This works fine. However, Google Maps also wants to update offline maps periodically (every 30 days, I think). It has an irritating habit of popping up a dialog asking for this when I'm *not* on WiFi (when I don't want to update, because 3G is slow and expensive). I normally cancel the dialog (I'm in the middle of doing something), but I can't find a way to force the update when I'm back on WiFi later in the day. This means I get the same irritating pop-up the next day.

Is there a way to force or manually trigger the updates to the offline maps?

(this is on an iPhone 5s, if it matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is almost one year after your post, but with the current version of Google Maps I have:

In Google Maps, go to the Menu, Select "Your places" > scroll down to "Offline maps" section